# Determining communities with single point of entry using ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, routing, route

I am attempting to determine the communities in a province that would have a single point of entry that could isolate the community if this road/bridge were closed (due to a weather event, for example).

Has anyone tackled a project like this before?

I feel it could be done within the Esri environment using Network Analyst, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Network Analyst could certainly handle a question like this, though it may not be necessary. Could you please elaborate on your issue a bit, though? For starters, do you have a road network layer, and is it already part of a Network Dataset? And for the communities, is it a point or polygon layer? Also worth considering: many communities straddle waterways. If you're not careful, you might come up with situations where a community is "accessible", but really only half of it is if the bridge in question happens to be in the middle of it.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I do have a road network layer but it is not currently a network dataset.
The communities are polygon layers, but I could use points if that would work better.

Comment: Where would these people be travelling *from* to these potentially cut off communities? Are you aware of this [accessibility dataset](https://map.ox.ac.uk/research-project/accessibility_to_cities/), hence me asking where they are coming from?